# Will this LINQ query enumerate through the entire enumeration?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to upload multiple files for an ASP.NET website. As such, I have the following simplified example:

```
public ContentResult UploadFiles(IList<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (files == null ||
        !files.Any())
    {
        // Nothing uploaded.
        return Content("No files where uploaded.");
    }

    myService.UploadCsvFilesToDatabaseAsync(files.Select(x => x.InputStream));

    return Content("Success!");
}
```

Notice this: `myService.UploadCsvFilesToDatabaseAsync(files.Select(x => x.InputStream)`

I do not want to enumerate through the files *at this point* .. but later on when I'm *inside* that method.

So, does `files.Select(x => x.InputStream)` do any enumerating *at this point* ? Or does it just pass in a new collection, which contains the *start* of each input stream, ready to be enumerated.

Clarification: I do not want to read any data in from the files *at this point* but a little bit later on inside, that method.

Comment: Looks like it shouldn't enumerate. A little bit of debugging can confirm that, simply put a breakpoint in the lambda, then put a breakpoint inside the method, and see which is hit first....

Comment: It won't do the whole list... but `.Any()` will take the first item if one is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, does files.Select(x => x.InputStream) do any enumerating at this
>   point ?

NO, quoting from [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its
>   **GetEnumerator** method directly or by using **foreach**

So until you are actually enumerating through it, it actually doesn't process the list. A simple test would be below

```
        List<int> intlist = new List<int>() {1,2,3};

        var result = intlist.Select(x => x);

        intlist.Add(12);

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

This would consider even the element which had been added after the LINQ expression. Would have it been eager loaded it would have not been included the element `12`.

Results In:

```
1
2
3
12
```

Update: For a complete example of both deferred execution AND already-executed, have a look at [this .NET fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FArwKI).

Comment: `.Select()` does not... but the `.Any()` call will use at least one.